# しゅうと／シュート - The great equalizer

Tags: words, meaning, loanwords, sports

I was watching the movie [Mr. Baseball](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104926/) the other day.  Several times during the movie they talk about `しゅうと` which they describe as "the great equalizer".  (Could possibly be `しゅうとう`, but their dialog does not sound like they're elongating the last syllable).

I've tried very unsuccessfully in finding this word in any of my multiple dictionaries.  Is this a common, known Japanese word?  Is it some kind of `野球用語`?  Is it just `外来語` of "shoot", or some word from another language?  If it's Japanese, does it have associated kanji?

Comment: If you write it in hiragana, it will most likely suggest mother-in-law, a different word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

シュート is a baseball term. It seems to me like different people have different terms for this pitch (although I'm no baseball expert).

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuuto) (which references Mr. Baseball, incidentally) and its talk page, it's a "shuuto" or "shootball" in English, but some people may recognize and describe it as a "sinker" or "reverse slider".

Comment: It is not particularly (only) a baseball term. It can also mean a shoot in basketball.

Comment: I would still describe "check" as a chess term, even if the same word can be used with a different meaning in [ice-hockey](http://www.sportsdefinitions.com/ice-hockey/Check.html) or other sports. But I understand what you're saying. :)

Comment: @sawa:  True, it can mean "shoot" in basketball, soccer, etc.  I guess the confusion was due to the fact that the word "shoot" is not a regular baseball term, so the movie made it sound like `しゅうと` was word of Japanese origin.